# Hard drive spins down after installing/updating .NET Framework

Tags: windows, windows-xp, hard-drive

This happens on a Windows XP Pro SP3 on a Seagate Barracuda SATA HDD. Intel ICH9R AHCI driver is installed via the F6 method.

Sometimes after I install .NET Framework 3.5 (or a .NET Framework update, for example) via Windows Update and let the system reboot, a BSOD appears for a very short time (less than a second) and the system reboots immediately (without showing the blue "Windows is shutting down" screen which it normally does) after which the drive spins down for some reason. Then during POST the drive spins up again. This has happened a few times to me already.

There are no error messages anywhere (Event Log is clean) and I haven't noticed any negative effects of this behavior. The drive itself is healthy (checked using Seagate's SeaTools diagnostic utility). The OS is freshly installed.

The problem always happens with .NET Framework related updates (or initial installation), never with any other updates. I wonder if they tax the drive so much that something goes wrong.

Any ideas why this happens?

EDIT: I was able to reproduce the problem. Again, it happened when installing .NET Framework (3.5). The BSOD message was as follows:

```
STOP: c000021a {Fatal System Error}
The Windows SubSystem system process terminated unexpectedly with a status of 0x0000005 (0x7c911766 0x0053f8ec).
The system has been shut down.
```

Again, no memory dump was created. The message is not too informative and since it happened again during .NET Framework installation, I guess it's just a bug related to it.

Comment: The drives shutting down at a BSOD is normal. [Turn off](http://kb.wisc.edu/page.php?id=7049) auto-restart to be able to see what information the BSOD is giving you (without having to jump through hoops).

Comment: I turned that off. Actually, I wanted to check the mini dump file, but it turns out it was not created for some reason. Does that say anything?

Comment: Maybe. Check the `System Failure` section of the `Startup and Recovery` dialog. Make sure that **(1)** *Write an event to the system log* is checked, **(2)** that either Kernel or Complete dump is selected, **(3)** that the dump file is a valid location and has enough space, and **(4)** that your pagefile settings include at least a 200MB pagefile on the system drive (eg `C:`).

Comment: Well, as I said it's a freshly installed system and all of that was configured by default. I have no idea why a mini dump was not created.

Comment: Could you solve this problem in the meantime? I have exactly the same issue.